# JWPlayer won't play multiple files

Tags: jwplayer

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here. I've been looking around on the internet for hours, trying different ways but I just can't get it to work. Please refer to the code below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var playerInstance = jwplayer('myElement');
playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: [{
        sources: [{
            file: 'files/6c497f2e7ed7f1b1723e405d979174c0.mp4',
            file: 'files/a97088dfc242fbc3141ab13db6df3380.mp4'
        }]
    }],
    listbar: {
        position: "right",
        size: 234
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to get it to show a playlist of those two video files to the side, which could then be selected and played. What it currently does is, it'll play the first file in the list, but it doesn't show the second file and also won't play it. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Verify that the location of second file is good by cut & pasting the url to the browser address bar.

Comment: yes, both paths are correct.

Comment: When you create a playlist like that, it's like a fallback video rather than a list. Standby I have a solution...

Comment: Alright, thank you in advance!

Comment: It's ready for review, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to play playlists with JW Player is to use an RSS playlist. The playlist's format is in JW Player's version of XML. The playlist must be on a server. The file's extension can be either .xml or .rss.
Here's the one used for the demo:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:jwplayer="https://rss.jwpcdn.com/">
<channel>
  <item>
    <title>Video 1</title>
    <jwplayer:source file="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid1.mp4" />
  </item>

  <item>
    <title>Video 2</title>
    <description></description>
    <jwplayer:source file="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid2.mp4" />
  </item>

  <item>
    <title>Video 3</title>
    <description></description>
    <jwplayer:source file="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid3.mp4" />
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

---

**REFERENCE**

[RSS Playlists](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406722-rss-playlist-embed)

[PHP Setup](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/developer-guide/embed_players/)

---

[**DEMO: CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/WwJdgK?editors=1000)

Comment: Many thanks for this. You're telling me that the extension needs to be either .xml or .rss - does this mean it's not possible for it to be .php? I'm ultimately looking to make the playlist dynamic using a database and such. Regardless, thank you for this.

Comment: You're welcome, sir. Yeah, it's basically XML with a twist of JW Player's flavor (minor syntactic differences.) References included in update. If you buy into JW7, you can use JSON which is pretty much a universal medium of data transfer. There's also a reference to PHP setup and a zip of PHP examples as well.